# Unable to set text of Telerik MVC menuitem without losing corresponding img

Tags: jquery, telerik-mvc

Using a telerik MVC menu. Following an ajax post I'm attempting to update the text of one of the menuitems but when I try to set the .text value it replaces everything with the supplied text. So in the following example I am trying to replace the 45 with a 46

Before: `<SPAN class=t-link><IMG class=t-image alt=image src="...srcinfo...">45</SPAN>`

jQuery: $('#MenuItemToChange').text('46')

After: "46"

Is there a way to set the inner HTML without losing everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Telerik menu creates each menu item as a `<LI>`.  Using the id of the `<LI>` use some jQuery similar to this:

```
$('#MenuItemId span').contents(':last').replaceWith('46');
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that that img tag is a part of the inner html, perhaps you could pull the whole  inner content out into a variable and match the bit at the end (either by matching a digit anchored at the end or by looking for the trailing ">" from the img tag.